# How to create an expression for a set of inputs?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

If I have the `x` as input for my discrete signal and I don't want to represent it as a vector, how can I transform it into an expression which gives me the same discrete signal?

```
n = -6:6
x = [0 0 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 0 0];
subplot(2,1,1);
stem(n,x);
```

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. [Curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) is an extremely broad discipline.

Comment: Lets say I have a drawing which is represented by an expression.I only know how my drawing looks like I don't know what is my expression.My question is how can I find out in this case the hidden expression.

Comment: for example if i have a drawing of a sin we know that the expression is sin(x) but what about a more complex sin?A normal sin(x) (first signal) and also a sin which doesn't have negative values (second signal) it starts from 0 and ends at 0 and its repeating

Comment: the vector represents that photo and i want to find an expression which represents that photo without using a vector

Answer (score 0):

The possible expressions that fit through your discrete signal are infinit, so no clear answer is possible. What is the purpose of your question? If you just want a smooth line through it, look for spline interpolation. If it is homework about fourier series, look for fourier series.